# bash script: check if directory name exists anywhere (not just in current path)?

Tags: bash, directory

How would I check if a directory name exists anywhere on a machine (not limited to the current working directory/subdirectories)? I'm using -d right now, but this only lets me know if the directory exists within the path I'm currently on.

example input:

```
./file.sh hello
```

expected:

```
script will search through computer to see if there's a directory 
anywhere named "hello" and return "yes"
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Have a look at `find` and `locate`.

Comment: use `find` to search your whole machine if that is your goal

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#!/bin/bash
find / -name "$1" -type d -print
```

Expect a lot of `Permission denied` errors if **not** running from root

Comment: You should quote `$1`, maybe my directory is called `*`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. makes sense :) fixed

Comment: I suggest: `find / ! -readable -prune -o -name "$1" -type d -print` to avoid `Permission denied` errors.

Comment: @Cyrus I get the error "find: -readable: unknown primary or operator" when I use this

Comment: @hack: I used `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`. I assume your find doesn't have option `-readable`.